# A Primer on Estimator Efficiency?

Tags: estimation, references, efficiency

Can someone recommend a text with derivations of classical estimator efficiency results? I'm particularly interested in likelihood and pseudo-likelihood estimators for multi-variate discrete models

Comment: You need to compute the Fisher matrix ? what is your model ? I am sure you can make your question more precise.

Comment: I could give more details if that's of interest...as an overview, I'm trying to compare efficiency/bias of n-iteration Contrastive Divergence estimator for fitting Boltzmann Machines with an estimator that uses n iterations of Belief Propagation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Asymptotic Statistics](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/asymptotic-statistics/A3C7DAD3F7E66A1FA60E9C8FE132EE1D)   by *A. W. van der Vaart* seems to serve the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

"Efficient" usually just means that in the class of estimators considered and for a given loss function, you choose one which is optimal.  If you look up "admissible" instead, you'll find a huge amount of information, though it's a slightly weaker criterion.